# If $f$ is holomorphic on an open unit disc. Then $|f'(z)|\le \frac{1}{1-|z|}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic map of the open unit disc into itself. Then $$|f'(z)|\le \frac{1}{1-|z|}$$
We can write $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n,\ |z|<1.$$ Also, $|f(z)|<1$. After this how I conclude that $|f'(z)|\le \frac{1}{1-|z|}$

Comment: $|f(z)|<1$ should be placed at the beginning : it is not good mathematical writing to say "also"... as if you were reminding of something later...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint 1. Note that by the [Schwarz–Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz.E2.80.93Pick_theorem) (which is an application of the maximum modulus principle), for all $z$ in the open unit disc,
$$|f'(z)|\le \frac{1-|f(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2}.$$

Hint 2. By the [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem), for  $|z|<1$ and for all $0<r<1-|z|$,
$$f'(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|w-z|=r}\frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^2}dw\implies |f'(z)|\leq \frac{2\pi r}{2\pi r^2}=\frac{1}{r}.$$

Comment: In the book, the author did not mentioned Schwarz Lemma before.

Comment: @Iampi  It is a straightforward application of the maximum modulus principle. See the proof in the wiki page.

Comment: But here $f(0)$ need not be $0$. And also, $|f'(z)|\le \frac{1-|f(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2}$.

Comment: @I am pi OK. See Hint 2.

Comment: But this proves that $|f'(z)|\le \frac{1}{(1-|z|)^2}$

Comment: @I am pi See my edited answer. Any further doubt?

Comment: Now I understood. Thanks a lot. :)